# RPi Zero W as bluetooth keyboard / mouse "passthrough"

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, hid

I'm looking for a solution to allow me to use the RPi Zero W as a gadget that will connect to my bluetooth keyboard and then present itself to my PC as a regular USB keyboard. This is workaround to allow me to use a favourite bluetooth keyboard with a PC that does not have/allow bluetooth connectivity. Any ideas on how to get this up and running?